# An ExecutableElement does not enclose its parameters, but a parameter VariableElement is enclosed by an ExecutableElement. Mistake?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

(This is [tagged with `annotation-processing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotation-processing) but here I'm just talking about [`javax.lang.model.element`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/package-summary.html) concepts.)

[`Element#getEnclosedElements()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getEnclosedElements()) says, in part (emphasis mine):

> A class or interface is considered to enclose the fields, methods, constructors, record components, and member classes and interfaces that it directly declares. A package encloses the top-level classes and interfaces within it, but is not considered to enclose subpackages. A module encloses packages within it. […] **Other kinds of elements are not currently considered to enclose any elements**….

So, among other things, if you call `getEnclosedElements()` on an [`ExecutableElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/ExecutableElement.html), I would expect the returned `List` to always be empty (at least until `javax.lang.model.element`'s rules change).

Then, [`Element#getEnclosingElement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getEnclosingElement()) says, in part:

> - If this is a method or constructor parameter, the executable element which declares the parameter is returned.

So given a [`VariableElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/VariableElement.html) with an [`ElementKind` of `PARAMETER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/ElementKind.html#PARAMETER), I'd expect an `ExecutableElement` with an [`ElementKind` of `METHOD`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/ElementKind.html#METHOD) (say) to be returned by [its `getEnclosingElement()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/VariableElement.html#getEnclosingElement()).

(The same sort of thing [is true of type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeParameterElement.html#getEnclosingElement()).)

This asymmetry seems odd to me.  Is it on purpose, or an oversight?